# Replace $ in Maven ant run

Tags: maven, replace, ant, escaping

i have to do this substitution in some files:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <replace token='${' value='${sys:' dir="${basedir}/target/dist/jboss">
                        <include name="log4j2.xml"/>
                    </replace>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I don't know how to escape `$` and I end up always to `"An Ant BuildException has occured: Syntax error in property: ${sys:"`
I tried to escape `$` with `\\$`, with `&#36;` , with `\$`, with `![CDATA[$]]` but none of this worked.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Il.K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the `${` in the `value` attribute. Try escaping it using double dollar symbols:

```
<replace token='${' value='$${sys:' dir="${basedir}/target/dist/jboss"> 
   <include name="log4j2.xml"/>
</replace>
```

Comment: i used ant instead of maven and follow your hint.
Now it's:
<replace token='$${' value='$${sys:' file='${basedir}/target/dist/jboss'/>

I have to escape even the token and it works.
Thank you, Happy Christmas to you. i'll retry with maven after the holidays.

Comment: Thank you. It works with ant run plugin too. <replace token='$${' value='$${sys:' dir="${basedir}/target/dist/jboss"> <include name="log4j2.xml"/> </replace>